# Настройка простейшего веб сервера на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно настроить на Ubuntu чтобы заработала связка LAMP и phpmyadmin?
Индексная страница сайта видится, но после ввода логина и пароля получаю ошибку `Ошибка подключения: Connection refused`. 
Вхожу в phpmyadmin под учетной записью пользователя, все работает. Подключение в коде также идет через эту учетную запись. Вот код:

```
<?

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "логин";
$password = "пароль";

// Создание подключения
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Проверка подключения
//if ($conn->connect_error) {

if ($conn) {
    die("Ошибка подключения: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

?>
```

В apache.conf прописал servername с указанием выделенного Ip.
В оболочке Ubuntu под пользователем Mysql также все входит. 
Я полный чайник в Ubuntu, подскажите что можно сделать?

Comment: с вероятностью, близкой к единице, mysqld сконфигурирован на использование сокета, а не tcp/ip. значит, вам надо [его указать](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) (путь к сокету см., например, в файле конфигурации mysqld). p.s. ну и базу данных, наверно, надо указать. ну и проверять надо совсем не то, что вы написали — см. первый пример по ссылке)

Comment: Спасибо, не подскажете "на пальцах" как прописать путь к сокету в файле конфигурации mysqld?

Comment: не надо его там «прописывать». он там уже есть. «прописывать» его надо параметром в используемой вами функции.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то мне нужно добавить $dbname, $port, $socket. А какое значение должно быть у порта и сокета?

Comment: И как быть если дальше для этого подключения используется другая БД?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы; если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.